# Encrypted Data SVG URL

Tags: javascript, encryption, svg

I was looking at the Guardian's website (http://www.theguardian.com/uk) and I noticed they use SVG file types to serve their images. What is strange is the URL path is encrypted with an extremely long line of random characters.

I was wondering if anyone know how they did this? Code or otherwise, and what advantage they gain from serving their content in this way.

An example of how they import fonts for example:

https://github.com/guardian/guss-webfonts/blob/master/webfonts/hinting-off/kerning-off/original/_How%20To%20Install%20Web%20Fonts.html

Another example of their URL is:

> content:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)

Comment: 1+ to @orcaman and you can use this tool to do so: http://www.base64-image.de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long string is not an encrypted string, it's a base64 encoded string representing the content. Using base64 strings is a way of representing binary data that may be used for inlining content instead of acquiring the content by other means (for example by supplying a URL from which the resource should be downloaded).

The [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) is a good example of this and this may also be used for SVGs.